# Chrome extension to refresh a page every minute and run a (javascript) script every time it refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension

**What I want:**
My propose is to check if new content was added in a page (that I do not own), so I was thinking to make a script that save the last content added in a cookie and refresh the page every minute: If the cookie doesn't match the last content added, that would mean there is new content and I would receive a notification.

Let's try with **pseudocode**:

**main_file:**

```
include: functions.js;

cookie last_content_added= get_first_paragraph();

//Refresh script
do (every_minute){
page_reload();
}
when.page.reload.complete {
run script_check_content
}
```

**functions.js**

```
script_check_content{
var content_check = get_first_paragraph();

if (content_check == cookie[last_content_added])
{
//do nothing
}
else{
//new content was added
play.notification.mp3

cookie[last_content.added] = get_first_paragraph();
}

}
```

Am I not thinking in an easier solution for what I'm looking for?

I'm new to chrome extensions, if you could separate the code in different files like it was a real extension, I would appreciate **very** much.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use  [*'chrome.tabs.query'*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query), use this to get all tabs that have the specified properties or all tabs if no properties are specified and  [*'chrome.tabs.executeScript'*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)  to inject the javascript code into a page that calls [*'window.location.reload()*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-reload). to refresh the page.

Here's a sample code to get the current tab and reload it using chrome.tab methods:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: false, currentWindow: true}, function (arrayOfTabs) {
var code = 'window.location.reload();';
chrome.tabs.executeScript(arrayOfTabs[0].id, {code: code});
});
```

Also, include '*onCompleted*' listener to listen when it is completely loaded and initialized.
 [chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function callback)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCompleted).

Comment: Is there a way to do it even if the tab isn't current "active"?

Comment: Yes, set the 'active' as false.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), it provides a way to react to changes in a DOM. You can provide a callback to react to DOM changes and don't need to use a timer.